# Good textbook for numerical methods in pde

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods

I am an engineering student and looking for programming numerical methods for pde. I will be using finite element and/or finite difference method. The book should, of course, outline numerical method but also should give emphasis on computer implementation. (I will program using python)

I checked several other related questions, but couldn't find exactly for my purpose.

[Good Textbook in Numerical PDEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085164/good-textbook-in-numerical-pdes?rq=1&newreg=0bbfbd1ec00944fca5fec940ee4635ef)

[Online resources to learn numerical methods for PDEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902136/online-resources-to-learn-numerical-methods-for-pdes)

Comment: This is a dangerous question. You're asking for opinions, after all, and you'll get opinionated answers. It's too broad, too. What is your PDE, elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic, linear, quasi-linear, non-linear,...? And in any of those cases, there are fashions (or even hypes), but which method is best, depends on the real problem, heavily .

Comment: Why not, e.g., [this book](http://a.co/3ki9AyI)?